# Cache: How to exempt just one block

Tags: drupal, drupal-blocks, drupal-cache

I've got a Drupal 6.x install, and there is one block generated by the Station module which displays the name of the show currently playing. Is there a way to make just that block exempt from caching?  Alternatively, can I insert a 'refresh' for only that block at 00:59:00 ?

I'm not a php guy, but have found the place in the module where this block is generated, and *think* I can make the change if I new what to do.

Comment: this block marked as BLOCK_NO_CACHE, for why you want to get it from cache? i assume, show playing station is realtime...

Answer (score 0):

If the block is a Javascript or jQuery widget the cache wouldn't bother you. eg: The page content is cached but runs a client side script that calls back to the server for the latest info and does an ajax thingy.

Alternatively, you could turn page cache off and set cache for some of the queries/element on that page. But if you're not a PHP guy that might be a struggle.

See:
http://api.drupal.org/api/function/cache_set/6

I'm sure there are other options people will help you with.